# convert numeric sas date to datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I am using **Pandas 0.18** and `read_sas` to load a `sas7bdat` dataset.

The dates in the Pandas dataframe appear as:

```
Out[56]: 
0    19411.0
1    19325.0
2    19325.0
3    19443.0
4    19778.0
Name: sas_date, dtype: float64
```

`pd.to_datetime` does not recognize this format. What should I do parse the date correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us what dates these numbers correspond to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this link](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm),

> [A] SAS date value is a value that represents the number of days between
>     January 1, 1960, and a specified date

Therefore, if we convert the numbers to Pandas Timedeltas and add them to
`1960-1-1` we can recover the date:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([19411.0, 19325.0, 19325.0, 19443.0, 19778.0])
ser = pd.to_timedelta(ser, unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
```

yields

```
0   2013-02-22
1   2012-11-28
2   2012-11-28
3   2013-03-26
4   2014-02-24
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```