# Datetime from SAS to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sas

How to convert SAS datetime (number of days from 1960-1-1) into pandas datetime format? I've read [convert numeric sas date to datetime in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412864/convert-numeric-sas-date-to-datetime-in-pandas) but maybe there is other solution to make it more quickly for a couple of million rows?

Comment: I think it is the best solution.